# How to write output error of console in xls format file in selenium-webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

If we want to Print the output Bug of a script in a xls file, So is there any way to achieve it?

[Pls see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caBFz.jpg)

Comment: I know how to write in a xls file. But the point is that how to extract the error displayed in console window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error displayed on console is an assertionerror or exception which you can capture either using any testng listner or try-catch block (Dirty way). once you have the message (error) then write it to excel file (As you already know how to write to excel I will skip this). Note: TestNG Listner also tells you which test failed with some other cool details you can use that info as well to print that info to spreadsheet. Let me know if you need further help!

Comment: Pls see the screenshot i added, and guide me

Comment: My Freind e.printStackTrace(); does not returns anything but prints the message to console. the return type is void. You can use e.getMessage(); or any other variant of e.getXXX() to get the message you desire.. Also try/catch is a dirty way in your case i would recommend you using TestNG Listners

Comment: if the solution was satisfactory consider accepting this as answer so that others would benefit from your query!!!